# jQuery tabs interfering with SimpleModal in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, simplemodal

I have a page that has two tabs created using jQuery, and I am also using Eric Martin's SimpleModal plugin.  However when I am in IE7, the SimpleModal overlay is appearing completely opaque, and not the 50% opacity I wanted.  If I remove the tabbing, the modals appear just fine.  I looked at the overlay style info in IE Dev Toolbar and it shows the overlay style as 50%, even though it is not showing that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more code it's tough to tell.

I would recommend using the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) if you can.  They're both made by the UI team and should work fine together.

Comment: Thanks... I decided to use the jQuery dialog.  It's just you have to do a lot more configuration with that.

Answer (score 0):

Eric Martin here ;)

Do you have a link or any sample code? I use tabs and SimpleModal in a number of places and have not had any issues...